# SparkSQL-How to reuse external tables?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use `df.save.option("path", "hdfs://xxx").writeAsTable(table)` to create tables in order to use CBO in future queries. The table creation takes a long time. I can see the persisted tables as parquet files but once I start another `spark-submit` application, there are no tables in catalog and I have to recreat again.

**I use Spark standalone without Hive installed. **

I tried it in `spark-shell` and it works fine. Once I restart `spark-shell`, the previous created tables are still there and I can directly query with `spark.sql("select * from previous_table")`.

Can anyone suggest what I should configure or add to make `spark-submit` behave the same as `spark-shell`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume both spark-shell and spark-submit are run from the same server (and by the way get the same spark configuration)

With spark-submit, you have to explicitly enable hive support to access the hive metastore when you create the sparkSession.

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate
// now access the metastore
spark.table("the_db.the_table").show
```